# Can't change width yet using {graphicx}

Tags: graphics, width, resize

I just finished installing LaTeX and I would like to resize an image but I'm getting the message "! Paragraph ended before \Gin@ii was complete.".

I am already using the package {graphicx} so I'm not sure what else I can do to fix this.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}

\includegraphics{width-12cm]{Databases_Table}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the bracket after `\includegraphics` is wrong. it needs to be a `[`

Comment: and `width=12cm`, not `-`

Comment: In case you want to use TeX's floating mechanism, you might want to enclose the image in a figure environment, e.g. `\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{Databases_Table}
\end{figure}`